# Jquery Enable and Disable option close from a dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I need to know how to enable or disable the close option of a Jquery dialog box.

First i open it:

```
$(".dialog-content").dialog('open');
```

Secondly i edit his content:

```
$(".dialog-body p").html("DO NOT CLOSE IT");
```

Thridly i need to disable his close option. Make some actions. And below enable his close option.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show close button like this:

```
$("#div1").dialog({                    // call .dialog method to create the dialog markup
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: true
});
```

// To hide

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

// To show

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
```

Comment: and for escape on close option ?

Comment: set   closeOnEscape: true for closing dialogbox on escape button

Comment: i mean how to enable or disable it when the dialog is already opened

Comment: i initialize my dialog like this and i want to change close option after she gets open $(".dialog-content").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 closeOnEscape: true,   
 modal: true,
 height: 'auto',
 width: 'auto',
 create: function(){
  $(this).css('maxWidth', dWidth);
 },
 show: {
  effect: 'fade',
  duration: 200
 },
 beforeClose: function() {
  $('.dialog-body p').css({
   color : '#052D92'
  });
  $('.dialog-body').css({
   color : '#052D92'
  });
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').css({
   display : 'none'
  });
 },  
 hide: {
  effect: 'fade',
  duration: 200
 }
});

Comment: after opening the dialogbox we cant change its property. we need to reinitialize dialogbox with its new property first and then again need to reopen the dialogbox.